# Receive A File Via PHP Web Service

Tags: php

I'm busy writing a PHP webservice and wish to receive a file as an array of byte streams (you can do something similar using C#) how can I do this in PHP? Using PHP 5 with NuSOAP.

Comment: You should provide some more detail as it's vital to know how the file is transmitted, e.g. base64-encoded within the SOAP message body or by using MTOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about php streams ? I have worked with streams in C# before, not in php, but seems like it should work :)

check out  [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/wezfurlong/php-streams-lucky-dip) ( starting from slide 18 )

good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you only need to send an URI and the client grab the file... no?

You can also encode the file with base64.